# Вывести строки из БД, исключающие конкретные значения (mysql)

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Как извлечь из таблицы только те строки, которые не содержат определенных значений, но соответствуют общему условию. 
Вот такой код:

```
//код...
elseif (($_POST['proizv'])=='other')
{
    $rslt="WHERE adm='1' AND rub='".$rub."' AND name=**гр1 и гр2 - нет, ост. - да**";
}
//код...
```

Выше я привожу условия, а далее, собственно, сам запрос.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,rub,name,title,text,price,pic,col,adm
                     FROM tovars ".$rslt." ORDER BY id LIMIT ".$col.",20");
```

Вот, собственно, и то, что мне необходимо: Как написать условие в $rslt так, чтобы из БД пришли строки, исключающие известные значения, но содержащие все остальные? Допустим, в столбце **name** есть **Группа1** и **Группа2** и некие остальные Группы. Вот Мне необходимо вывести все, кроме Группы1 и 2...
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.

```
WHERE name NOT IN ('Группа1', 'Группа2')
```